# Holonomy group of Möbius strip

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the Möbius bundle over $S^1$, $M=\mathbb{R}^2/\sim$, where $\sim$ is given by:
$(t,v)\sim (t',v')$ iff: $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z} : t'=t+k,v'=(-1)^kv$, and projection $\pi:M\to S^1$, given by: $\pi([t,1])=e^{2\pi i t}$.
Can you give an example of a connection on $M$? What is the holonomy group of $M$?

---

For the first question. I know by a sketch of solution that the connection is the connection $\nabla$ for which the local section $s:S^{1}\backslash\{1\}\to M$, $s(z)=[\arg(z)/2\pi,1]$, is parallel. My question is how to find such connection?

---

For the second question. Intuitively, given $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, let $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ be a piecewise-smooth path, with $\gamma(0)=p=\gamma(1)$, i have to find that parallel transport: $\pi_\gamma: T_pM\to T_pM$, is : $\pi_\gamma(v)=-v$, and so Hol$_p(\nabla)=O(1)$. If it is correct, i want to find a more detailed proof.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't just post literal homework questions and expect us to do them for you. Include discussion about what you've tried and what you understand and what you do not understand.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I will try to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's arguably clear from context, but often we will not say "the holonomy of $M$" but rather "the holonomy of $\nabla$". After all, varying the connection $\nabla$ on a fixed smooth manifold $M$ products different holonomy groups.

To make clear something implicit in the problem statement:

If $(t, v) \sim (t', v')$ then $t' - t \in \Bbb Z$, so $\sim$ induces an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$, namely $t \approx t'$ iff $t' - t \in \Bbb Z$. But this is exactly the identification of elements of $\Bbb R$ made by the quotient map $\Bbb R \to S^1$, $t \mapsto e^{2 \pi i t}$, so the projection $p : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ onto the first factor---which we can view as the bundle projection for the trivial bundle on $\Bbb R$ with fiber $\Bbb R$---fits into a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Bbb R^2 & \stackrel\sim\to & M \\
p\downarrow \phantom{p}& & \phantom{\pi}\downarrow\pi \\
\Bbb R & \stackrel\approx\to & S^1
\end{array}
$$

**Hints**

(1) First, the connection in the solution sketch you mentioned is certainly not the only one, but it is a natural choice. Since the base $S^1$ is $1$-dimensional, for any nonvanishing local section $s : U \to M \vert_U$ there is a single (linear) vector bundle connection $\nabla$ on $U$ for which $s$ is parallel.

If we denote $U := S^1 - \{ 1 \}$, the section you mention is:
$$s : U \to M\vert_U , \qquad s : z \mapsto \left[\frac{1}{2 \pi} \arg z, 1\right] .$$
Once we find such a connection, continuity implies that there is at most one connection on $M$ that restricts to this one---put another way, either the connection lines up with itself as $z \to 1$ from both sides or it does not.

To describe the connection in a local trivialization, we can take inspiration from the definition of $s$ to define the trivialization $$\Phi : M\vert_U \stackrel{\cong}{\to} U \times \Bbb R, \qquad [z, v] \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \arg z, v\right)$$ on $S^1 - \{ 1 \}$. With respect to this trivialization the function $U \to \Bbb R$ corresponding to our section is just $z \mapsto 1$.

**Remark** I'm not sure whether you have the relevant tools yet, but I'd prefer to construct such a connection without referring to local trivializations. After all, this would save us the final step of the process above.

In brief: The equivalence relation $\sim$ is evidently the one induced by the group action
$$\Bbb Z \times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 , \qquad k \cdot (t, v) \mapsto (t + k, (-1)^k v)$$
of $\Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb R^2$, so if we can find connection on the bundle $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ that is preserved under the action of $\Bbb Z$, it will descend to a connection on $M \to S^1$. The bundle map projection $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is just projection onto the first coordinate, giving the preferred connection $H := T\Bbb R \oplus \{0\} \subset \Bbb R^2$. The differential of the action of $k \in \Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is $\operatorname{id} \oplus (-1)^k \operatorname{id}$, but this map preserves the distribution $H = T\Bbb R \oplus \{0\}$, so $H$ descends to a connection on $M \to S^1$. One can check directly that this coincides with the connection we constructed above.

(2) It's not true that $\pi_\gamma : T_p M \to T_p M$ is $\pi_\gamma : v \mapsto -v$ for all $\gamma$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = p$---after all, the parallel transport along the constant curve $c_p(t) = p$ is just the identity map $\operatorname{id}_{T_p M}$.

More generally, for a connection on a bundle $E \to N$ over a $1$-dimensional base, the parallel transport along any contractible loop is the identity map. Thus, the parallel transport map $\pi_\gamma$ in fact depends only on the homotopy class $[\gamma]$ of $\gamma$, that is, the group homomorphism $\Omega_p(N) \to GL(E_p)$, $\gamma \mapsto \pi_\gamma$, descends to a homomorphism $$\pi_1(N, p) \to GL(E_p), \qquad [\gamma] \mapsto \pi_\gamma,$$ and $\operatorname{Hol}_p(\nabla)$ is the image of this homomorphism. Since $\pi_1(S^1)$ is infinite cyclic, say with generator $[\alpha]$, the holonomy group is the cyclic subgroup of $GL(M_p)$ generated by $\pi_\alpha$, and hence it suffices to compute that map.